# Discord.Js online presence update loop fix

Tags: discord.js

I made a bot that watches if a member goes online and gives a welcome gif.

I am trying to make the bot to wait when more than 1 goes online for each user because it can be annoying to see a couple of gifs from the same person (like logon spam).

Here is my work

```
bot.on("presenceUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if(newMember.presence.status === 'online')
        {
        console.log(`${newMember.user.username} is now ${newMember.presence.status}`);
        bot.channels.get('id').send(`${newMember.user.username} **online**`, {
            files: [
                "gif"
                ]
            })
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you only want 1 message per user in a certain timeframe or 1 per x users in a certain timeframe?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [Discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org), you can see that [Game class](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Game) has a `name` property. It's this property which is equal to the name of the game.

So replace `newMember.presence.game.state` with `newMember.presence.game.name`.

Comment: yeah yeah, I was mistaken when I wrote this, I tried game.name and it is working but the problem is that the user can log on and off and it can be annoying and also it also sometimes stuck on a loop and can give me 10 logons and msgs ... frustrating